# How to concatenate Ogg with JS?

Tags: javascript, ogg, vorbis

In my webapp user can download OGG (vorbis), but I found that for example VLC show one file duration as 35 seconds but play it for ten minutes.

Currently I build a file for downloading with:

```
const blob = new Blob(listOfChunksBlobs, {'type': 'audio/ogg'});
```

[image: vlc]

With `xdd` I checked the start of the OGG - but I do not see how I can alter anything here:

```
00000000: 4f67 6753 0002 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  OggS............
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 5664 269e 011e 0176 6f72  ......Vd&....vor
00000020: 6269 7300 0000 0001 2256 0000 0000 0000  bis....."V......
00000030: 058a 0000 0000 0000 a901 4f67 6753 0000  ..........OggS..
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000050: 5096 ab47 0e16 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  P..G............
00000060: ffff c503 766f 7262 6973 0600 0000 6666  ....vorbis....ff
00000070: 6d70 6567 0000 0000 0105 766f 7262 6973  mpeg......vorbis
00000080: 2242 4356 0100 4000 0018 4210 2a05 ad63  "BCV..@...B.*..c
00000090: 8e3a c815 218c 19a2 a042 ca29 c71d 42d0  .:..!....B.)..B.
000000a0: 21a3 2443 883a c635 c718 6347 b964 8a42  !.$C.:.5..cG.d.B
000000b0: c981 d090 5500 0040 0000 a41c 5750 7249  ....U..@....WPrI
000000c0: 2de7 9c73 a318 57cc 71e8 20e7 9c73 e520  -..s..W.q. ..s. 
000000d0: 67cc 7109 25e7 9c73 8e39 e792 728e 31e7  g.q.%..s.9..r.1.
000000e0: 9c73 a318 570e 7229 2de7 9c73 8114 478a  .s..W.r)-..s..G.
000000f0: 71a7 18e7 9c73 a41c 478a 71a8 18e7 9c73  q....s..G.q....s
00000100: 6d31 b792 72ce 39e7 9c73 e620 8752 72ae  m1..r.9..s. .Rr.
00000110: 35e7 9c73 a418 670e 720b 25e7 9c73 c620  5..s..g.r.%..s. 
00000120: 67cc 71eb 20e7 9c73 8c35 b7d4 72ce 39e7  g.q. ..s.5..r.9.
00000130: 9c73 ce39 e79c 73ce 39e7 9c73 8c31 e79c  .s.9..s.9..s.1..
00000140: 73ce 39e7 9c73 6e31 e716 73ae 39e7 9c73  s.9..sn1..s.9..s
00000150: ce39 e71c 73ce 39e7 9c73 2034 6415 0090  .9..s.9..s 4d...
00000160: 0000 a0a1 288a e228 0e10 1ab2 0a00 c800  ....(..(........
00000170: 0010 4071 1447 9114 4bb1 1ccb d124 0d08  ..@q.G..K....$..
00000180: 0d59 0500 0001 0008 0000 a048 86a4 488a  .Y.........H..H.
00000190: a558 8e66 699e 267a a228 9aa2 2aab b269  .X.fi.&z.(..*..i
000001a0: cab2 2ccb b2eb ba2e 101a b20a 0048 0000  ..,..........H..
000001b0: 5051 14c5 7014 0708 0d59 0500 6400 0008  PQ..p....Y..d...
000001c0: 6028 8aa3 388e e458 92a5 599e 0784 86ac  `(..8..X..Y.....
000001d0: 0200 8000 0004 0000 500c 47b1 144d f124  ........P.G..M.$
000001e0: cff2 3ccf f33c cff3 3ccf f33c cff3 3ccf  ..<..<..<..<..<.
000001f0: f33c cff3 3c0d 080d 5905 0020 0000 0082  .<..<...Y.. ....
00000200: 2864 1803 4243 5601 0040 0000 0821 1a19  (d..BCV..@...!..
00000210: 439d 5212 5c0a 1642 1c11 431d 42ce 43a9  C.R.\..B..C.B.C.
00000220: a583 e029 8525 63d2 53ac 4108 217c ef3d  ...).%c.S.A.!|.=
00000230: f7de 7bef 81d0 9055 0000 1000 0061 1438  ..{....U.....a.8
00000240: 8881 c724 0821 8462 1427 4471 a620 0821  ...$.!.b.'Dq. .!
00000250: 84e5 2458 ca79 e824 08dd 8310 42b8 9c7b  ..$X.y.$....B..{
00000260: cbb9 f7de 7b20 3464 1500 0008 00c0 2084  ....{ 4d...... .
00000270: 1042 0821 8410 4208 29a4 9452 4829 a698  .B.!..B.)..RH)..
00000280: 628a 29c7 1c73 cc31 c720 830c 32e8 a093  b.)..s.1. ..2...
00000290: 4e3a c9a4 924e 3aca 24a3 8e52 6b29 b514  N:...N:.$..Rk)..
000002a0: 534c b1e5 1663 adb5 d69c 73af 4129 638c  SL...c....s.A)c.
000002b0: 31c6 1863 8c31 c618 638c 31c6 1823 080d  1..c.1..c.1..#..
000002c0: 5905 0080 0000 1006 1964 9041 0821 8414  Y........d.A.!..
000002d0: 5248 29a6 9872 cc31 c71c 0342 4356 0100  RH)..r.1...BCV..
000002e0: 8000 0002 0000 001c 4552 2447 7224 4792  ........ER$Gr$G.
000002f0: 24c9 922c 4993 3ccb b33c cbb3 3c4d d444  $..,I.<..<..<M.D
00000300: 4d15 55d5 556d d7f6 6d5f f66d dfd5 65df  M.U.Um..m_.m..e.
00000310: f665 dbd5 655d 9665 ddb5 6d5d d65d 5dd7  .e..e].e..m].]].
00000320: 755d d775 5dd7 755d d775 5dd7 755d d781  u].u].u].u].u]..
00000330: d090 5500 8004 0080 8ee4 388e e438 8ee4  ..U.......8..8..
00000340: 488e a448 0a10 1ab2 0a00 9001 0010 0080  H..H............
00000350: a338 8ae3 488e e458 8e25 5992 2669 9667  .8..H..X.%Y.&i.g
00000360: 7996 a779 9aa8 891e 101a b20a 0000 0400  y..y............
00000370: 1000 0000 0000 80a2 288a a338 8e24 5996  ........(..8.$Y.
00000380: a669 9ea7 7aa2 289a aaaa 8aa6 a9aa aa6a  .i..z.(........j
00000390: 9aa6 699a a669 9aa6 699a a669 9aa6 699a  ..i..i..i..i..i.
000003a0: a669 9aa6 699a a669 9aa6 699a a669 9aa6  .i..i..i..i..i..
000003b0: 6902 a121 ab00 0009 0000 1dc7 711c 4771  i..!........q.Gq
000003c0: 1cc7 7124 4792 2420 3464 1500 2003 0020  ..q$G.$ 4d.. .. 
000003d0: 0000 4351 1c45 722c c792 344b b33c cbd3  ..CQ.Er,..4K.<..
000003e0: 44cf f45c 5136 7553 576d 2034 6415 0000  D..\Q6uSWm 4d...
000003f0: 0800 2000 0000 0000 00c7 733c c773 3cc9  .. .......s<.s<.
00000400: 933c cb73 3cc7 933c 49d3 344d d334 4dd3  .<.s<..<I.4M.4M.
00000410: 344d d334 4dd3 344d d334 4dd3 344d d334  4M.4M.4M.4M.4M.4
00000420: 4dd3 344d d334 4dd3 344d d334 4dd3 344d  M.4M.4M.4M.4M.4M
00000430: d334 4d03 4243 5602 0064 0000 1093 904a  .4M.BCV..d.....J
00000440: 4eb1 5746 29c6 24b4 5e2a a414 93d4 7ba8  N.WF).$.^*....{.
00000450: 9862 4c3a eda9 4206 2907 b987 4a21 a5a0  .bL:..B.)...J!..
00000460: d3de 32a5 9052 0c7b a798 42c8 18ea a183  ..2..R.{..B.....
00000470: 9031 85b0 d7da 73cf bdf7 1e08 0d59 1100  .1....s......Y..
00000480: 4401 0000 c620 c610 63c8 3126 2583 1231  D.... ..c.1&%..1
00000490: c724 6452 22e7 9c94 4e4a 26a5 a456 5acc  .$dR"...NJ&..VZ.
000004a0: a484 984a 8b91 734e 4a27 2593 525a 0ba9  ...J..sNJ'%.RZ..
000004b0: 6592 4a6b 25a6 0200 0002 1c00 0002 2c84  e.Jk%.........,.
000004c0: 4243 5604 0051 0000 8831 4829 a414 524a  BCV..Q...1H)..RJ
000004d0: 31a7 9843 4a29 c794 6348 29e5 9c72 4e39  1..CJ)..cH)..rN9
000004e0: c798 7410 2ae7 1874 0e4a a494 728e 39a7  ..t.*..t.J..r.9.
000004f0: 9c73 1232 0795 730e 4226 9d00 0080 0007  .s.2..s.B&......
00000500: 0080 000b a1d0 9015 0140 9c00 0080 9073  .........@.....s
00000510: 8a31 0811 6310 4209 2985 5052 aa9c 93d2  .1..c.B.).PR....
00000520: 4149 a983 9252 49a9 c592 528c 9573 523a  AI...RI...R..sR:
00000530: 0929 7512 522a 29c5 5852 8a2d a454 6369  .)u.R*).XR.-.Tci
00000540: 2dd7 d252 8d2d c69c 5b8c bd86 9462 2da9  -..R.-..[....b-.
00000550: d55a 5aab b9c5 5873 8b35 f7c8 394a 9d94  .ZZ...Xs.5..9J..
00000560: d63a 29ad a5d6 6a4d add5 da49 692d a4d6  .:)...jM...Ii-..
00000570: 6269 2dc6 d662 cd29 c69c 3329 ad85 9662  bi-..b.)..3)...b
00000580: 2ba9 c5d8 62cb 35b5 9873 692d d714 63cf  +...b.5..si-..c.
00000590: 29c6 9e6b acb9 c79c 8330 add5 9c5a cb39  )..k.....0...Z.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is because of the same `serial` of my every ogg, for example result from `ogginfo`:

```
Note: Stream 1 has serial number 0, which is legal but may cause problems with some tools.
New logical stream (#1, serial: 00000000): type vorbis
Vorbis headers parsed for stream 1, information follows...
Version: 0
Vendor: ffmpeg
Channels: 1
Rate: 22050

Nominal bitrate: 35.333000 kb/s
Upper bitrate not set
Lower bitrate not set
Vorbis stream 1:
    Total data length: 2048 bytes
    Playback length: 0m:00.415s
    Average bitrate: 39.435345 kb/s
Logical stream 1 ended
```

For correct Ogg concatenation we must have unique `serial` per every file with correct `crc`. I did not found existing JS snippets for that (please feel free to comment/answer with your JS), only [C code for a few hundreds of lines](https://git.xiph.org/?p=rogg.git;a=blob;f=rogg_serial.c) that you can use on the backend or compile to WASM (230K for generated JS and 59K for the `wasm` file) - or I hope that somebody will rewrite it to JS - I have no knowledge of C.

[Original message from Ralph Giles in Ogg mailing list:](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/ogg-dev/2018-November/001946.html)

> Note if *both* files have the same serial number, it's impossible to 
>   find the points where they were concatentated by bisection, and most 
>   tools will assume they've found all the sections and calculate an 
>   incorrect duration. They can still be played individually because
>   there  is not concatenation boundary to find in the individual case.
>
> If ogginfo shows the same serial (00000000) for both of your input 
>   streams, that's likely the problem. Muxers are supposed to use a
>   random  serial number to make conflicts unlikely. You can fix them by
>   rewriting  the serial number so there's no conflict. Basically, you
>   change the  serialno field in each ogg page header and then update the
>   crc.

UPDATE: This is the gif with serials `11111111` and `22222222` - I think that if we get Oggs from the same source in the same format (for example AWS Polly) - maybe it will be much simpler to alter hardcoded positions for serial and crc32.

UPDATE: Yes set unique serial for every Ogg chunk (to all "pages" of that chunk) and set correct CRC32 (again for all pages of every Ogg), see the [documentation of Ogg](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/framing.html) and [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg_page); also see [this answer about how to build CRC32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442047/1879101). And do not forget that all hexes must be 8 characters long, so `const hex = crc.toString(16).padStart(8, '0')`

[image: ogg hex xxd serial]

Comment: I found that with that approach the seeking is broken :( Maybe I need to remove headers from every audio file...